airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://demo-spark-master:7077 --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18
repository
I create an airflow DAG to submit spark job to the spark cluster that reads data from postgresql database. but i got error. i don't know how to fix it. i already tried to install spark, airflow, and also change port many times. but still get the same issue. please help me what should i do? thank you this is error that i get
i expect that i can submit spark job to spark cluster.
